# Django admin CSS randomly gone

Tags: django, django-admin

I was working on the admin interface of my Django project, trying to get the right fields to show up in the right form, then on one of the reloads the CSS stopped loading, the Chrome inspector tells me the CSS files return a 404 error. I don't know what happened and can't figure it out.

It's not a static files issue - the project doesn't use static files at all, and the staticfiles app has been commented out in settings.py (this is not recent, the CSS has been working for weeks without it). Debug is set to True (this also is not recent), however the project isn't served by runserver anyway.

I've tried destroying and recreating the virtual machine the project is running on, which means literally everything except the project's own files is 100% fresh. Problem still persists.

The question is, what can I do to get CSS working again?

Comment: 'the project doesn't use static files at all', yes it does. It should load the admin css. CSS is a static file. Things don't just stop working. If it worked before you should take a step back and see what you did different. You can also read the docs about serving static files in development: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that the project doesn't use Django's system for static files, at least not directly. I don't know what the admin page does, but it has been serving the CSS files without the staticfiles app being enabled for weeks.

And I really didn't do anything different, I was working on the get_fieldsets method on my UserAdmin class when the CSS broke between reloads, and all I had done for the past few hours was work on that class.

Comment: So the serving of static files is done by some server (Apache, NGINX or whatever) so you should inspect the server config. Does it serve static files? Django has the collectstatic management command. Run it to collect all static files in the static dir. So that it can be served by your server.

Comment: The server is Daphne, which as far as I can tell doesn't have a server config. It's been serving the CSS files so far. The collectstatic command is provided by the staticfiles app which as I mentioned is commented out. I did try enabling it and running that command, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: After comparing with a fresh project, enabling staticfiles seems to solve the issue. I'm not convinced this is related to the cause of the problem though, as staticfiles have literally never been enabled for this project so I don't understand how the CSS files got served in the first place.